# ejs template placing things out of order

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, ejs

I am using an ejs template to loop through an array and add rows to a table. Here is the following code in my template:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Title
        </th>
        <th>
          Creator
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="createNewBoard">
        <th scope="row">
          Add New
        </th>
        <td>
          +
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% boards.forEach(function(board) { %>
        <a href="/<%= board._id %>">
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">
              <%= board.title %>
            </th>
            <td>
              <%= board.creator %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </a>
      <% }) %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And here is what is produced:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <a href="/584654b4c834f13ea05cf831"></a>
  <a href="/5846563e97b6133f6832568d"></a>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Title
        </th>
        <th>
          Creator
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="createNewBoard">
        <th scope="row">
          Add New
        </th>
        <td>
          +
        </td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">
              Yooo
            </th>
            <td>
              gus.henry@me.com
            </td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">
              Swag
            </th>
            <td>
              gus.henry@me.com
            </td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Why is it placing the anchor tags at the top, rather than in the table rows? Other than ejs, using bootstrap.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with the way tables are parsed in compliant browsers (i.e. chrome).

your `<a>` tag should be inside a `<td></td>` to be valid HTML, and chrome for one will move it out of the `<tbody>` when it renders the page. 
Because ejs is interpreted by the server, the browser never sees any of the ejs `<% %>` stuff - so do a 'view source' on your output page and you'll see the `<a>` tags where you expected them to be.

It looks like you're trying to cause a click on a table row to navigate to your `/[board id]` page. You can instead do something like the this:

```
<% boards.forEach(function(board) { %>
      <tr onclick="javascript:window.location='/<%= board._id %>';">
        <th scope="row">
          <%= board.title %>
        </th>
        <td>
          <%= board.creator %>
        </td>
      </tr>
<% }) %>
```

Or, if you really want a non-javascript solution, you could position an `<a>` tag absolutely (so it covers the cell) in each `<td>` and `<th>` as follows:

```
<% boards.forEach(function(board) { %>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">
          <%= board.title %>
          <a class="coveringA" href="/<%= board._id %>"></a>
        </th>
        <td>
          <%= board.creator %>
          <a class="coveringA" href="/<%= board._id %>"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
<% }) %>
```

with accompanying css as follows:

```
table td { 
      overflow:hidden;
}

.coveringA { 
      position:absolute; 
      display:block;
      top:0px; 
      left:0px; 
      right:0px; 
      bottom:0px;
      background:rgba(0,0,0,0); /* sets an invisible background to ensure its clickable in IE9 */
}
```